# Inject variable as Array parameter

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode

I have var:

```
// Russia, US, and other country, its dynamical changing
var mytest = someTextLabel.text
```

and I need to inject 'mytest' as a Dictionary parameter after JSON parsing:

```
// compile error, dailyStat don't have member 'mytest'
self.myArray = dailyStat.mytest.map{ Double($0.recovered) }
```

`dailyStat` have the following structure:

```
struct dailyStat: Codable {
    let france: [CovidNums]
    let russia: [CovidNums]
    let us: [CovidNums]
    let brazil : [CovidNums]
    let uk: [CovidNums]
    let spain: [CovidNums]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case us = "US"
        case russia = "Russia"
        case france = "France"
        case brazil = "Brazil"
        case uk = "United Kingdom"
        case spain = "Spain"
    }
}

struct CovidNums: Codable {
    let date: String
    let confirmed, deaths, recovered: Int
}
```

I don't want to use case switch:

```
switch mytest {
    case "Russia"
        self.myArray = dailyStat.russia.map{ Double($0.recovered) }
    case "US"
        self.myArray = dailyStat.us.map{ Double($0.recovered) }
    ...
```

since I have 100 countries

Comment: Where is `mytest` in `DailyStat`?

Comment: mytest its only variable, I need use this var as a Array parametr

Comment: Your `dailyStat` object has a property for each country? Would it not have been better to use a `[String, [CovidNums]]` dictionary, or if you wanted to type safety, you could create an enum of all the countries

Comment: Maybe you should use `[String: [CovidNums]]` dictionary instead of `DailyStat`. Or `[CountryEnum: [CovidNums]]`. That way you will be able to subscript with a key, and you won't need to modify your structure when countries list will change.

Comment: How it will be in swift?

Answer (score 0):

You should better write all your countries to one variable:

```
var countries: Dictionary<String: CovidNums>
```